# Is it possible to use namespaces in swagger 3.0 definitions

Tags: php, swagger, openapi

Sometimes I need to define a few similar parameters.
Is it possible to use some kind of namespace in swagger, so I could do:

`@OA\Parameter(ref="#/components/parameters/id/int")`
`@OA\Parameter(ref="#/components/parameters/id/uuid")`

so each would have a slightly different definition?

Eg. something like this:

```yaml
components:
  parameters:
    id:
      int:
        in: path
        name: id
        schema:
          type: integer
        required: true
        description: "id"
        example: 1
      uuid:
        in: path
        name: id
        schema:
          type: string
        required: true
        description: "uuid"
        example: "b5fd728d-1c78-4085-89ba-579574b5831f"
```

Comment: why not define 2 different parameters `numericId` and `uuid`? and use them as:
`@OA\Parameter(ref="#/components/parameters/numericId")`
`@OA\Parameter(ref="#/components/parameters/uuid")`

Comment: That's what we are doing now, but I am looking for a cleaner solution, since it was working for small projects, but the bigger the project is getting the harder it is to find a good non-conflicting name